# SQL select / group

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am a student this is homework.  I'm getting tired and confused.  Any advice will be appreciated.

I have two tables.

**Employee** has the following columns:

- Last_name
- First_name
- Address
- Phone
- Job_title(FK)
- Wage

**Job_title** has

- job_title(PK)
- EEO classification
- Job_description
- Exempt_Non_Exempt

I need to select the employees’ last names and group them by salary within job titles that are grouped into exempt and non-exempt.

I'm using sql server to check my work but it needs to be hand scripted.

Comment: Did you word your question correctly?

You would want some kind of aggregate to work on the columns that are not grouped. For instance, getting the maximum or average salary and grouping by job title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you provide sample data?  Because it's not clear to me what the data type for `JOB_TITLE.exempt_non_exempt` is, or what is to be accomplished by the specified grouping criteria - `EMPLOYEE.last_name` will be mostly unique (but it can't be guaranteed due to the Mr. Smith principle), so it sounds like there's a need for aggregate function use.

Based on what I've read, this looks to be what you're after:

```
  SELECT e.last_name, e.wage, jt.exempt_non_exempt
    FROM EMPLOYEE e
    JOIN JOB_TITLE jt ON jt.job_title = e.job_title
GROUP BY e.last_name, e.wage, jt.exempt_non_exempt
```

You join on the foreign/primary key to get valid data from both tables.

The GROUP BY clause is where you define grouping, but SQL standard is that if you specify columns in the SELECT clause without being wrapped in aggregate functions (IE: COUNT/MAX/MIN/etc), then those columns need to be specified in the GROUP BY.